# installing react using npx create-react-app is showing an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.959]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ashish>node --version
v12.18.3

C:\Users\Ashish>npm --version
6.14.6

C:\Users\Ashish>npx create-react-app demo

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Ashish\demo.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Ashish\demo\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Ashish\demo\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Ashish\demo\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
- react-scripts@3.4.3
- cra-template@1.0.3
  added 1582 packages from 745 contributors in 287.742s

65 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

Git repo not initialized Error: Command failed: git --version
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
at execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
at tryGitInit (C:\Users\Ashish\demo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:46:5)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Ashish\demo\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:266:7)
at [eval]:3:14
at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:18)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) {
status: 1,
signal: null,
output: [ null, null, null ],
pid: 7836,
stdout: null,
stderr: null
}

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library/dom/-/dom-6.16.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-14T18_26_30_336Z-debug.log
`npm install --save @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2` failed

C:\Users\Ashish>

Comment: Based on that 2nd last paragraph: `ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library/dom/-/dom-6.16.0.tgz failed` it seems like you're having some network problems. Are you behind a proxy like the error message suggests you might be?

Comment: Also a couple things to help us help you: 1) could you please format your console output  using 3 back-ticks, like so:  ```. 2) could you also add some description in the body of the question which describes what you're expecting to happen and how it's going wrong, as well as what you've tried. -- 
Thanks! :)